# Remove JButton using method of KeyListner Interface

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, grid-layout

I used ArrayList to put buttons into JFrame,
and now I want to make a program which removes the JButton with pressing specific key.

However, when I press the key, the button on the frame doesn't get removed,
but it does from the arraylist.

To make above function available, should I change my frame code?
Here's my code for the frame part

```
public class DataModel extends JFrame {
    JPanel _panel = new JPanel();
    Tiles _tiles;

    public DataModel(Tiles tiles) {

        this._tiles = tiles;

        setVisible(true);
        _panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < _tiles.size(); i++) {
            _panel.add(_tiles.get(i));
        }

        add(_panel);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: This seems more like the case for a `JList` ..

Answer (score 1):

> However, when I press the key, the button on the frame doesn't get removed, but it does from the arraylist.

The basic code when adding/removing components from a visible GUI is:

```
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // repaint components after layout manager has done its job
```

Comment: Is there any specific method to delete JButton on JPanel?
I used panel.remove(comp) method, but doesnt work.

Comment: @Javarian If you have a proper reference to the button and the panel, then the code will work. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a frame with some buttons. Add an ActionListener to each button the invokes the code I suggested. The code should work. If not, then you have simple code to post of the forum.

Comment: I found out that the remove method worked, however the nbutton on the panel still exists..

Comment: @Javarian, `however the nbutton on the panel still exists` - no idea what that means. How do you expect us to help when we have no idea what your code looks like. You have been asked to post your `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem. If you can't do that then we can't help you.

Comment: I was talking about JButton, not nbutton. I'll put additional codes soon